$\Sigma_n$ action on algebras of symmetric monoidal $\infty$-categories
Let $\mathcal{C}^\otimes$ be a symmetric monoidal ($\infty$)-category. In $1$-category theory, given $X^{\otimes n} \in \mathcal{C}$, there is an action on the permutation group $\Sigma_n \curvearrowright X^{\otimes n}$ (here $\Sigma_n$ is seen as the 1-groupoid with one object, and the action is encoded by a functor $\Sigma_n \to \mathcal{C})$. The same is true in $\infty$-category theory; here the action is given by a functor $B \Sigma_n \to \mathcal{C}$, and to build the above action one can see HA, Ex. 6.1.4.2. From my understanding, Lurie considers the simplicial set $$\mathcal{C}^{(n)} := \mathcal{C}^{\times n} \times_{\Sigma_n} E \Sigma_n,$$ where $\Sigma_n$ acts pointwise on $\mathcal{C}^{\times n}$ by permuting the factors; then the functor given by symmetric monoidality $\mathcal{C}^{\times n} \simeq \mathcal{C}^\otimes_{\left<n\right>} \to \mathcal{C}$ factors through the above quotient and yields a functor
$$
\mathcal{C}^{(n)} \to \mathcal{C}.
$$
By picking out an object $\Delta^0 \simeq (\ast)^{\times n} \to \mathcal{C}^{\times n}$, on then gets the functor encoding the permutations:
$$
\ast \times_{\Sigma_n} E \Sigma_n \simeq B \Sigma_n \to \mathcal{C}^{(n)} \to \mathcal{C}, \quad \ast \mapsto X \otimes \dots \otimes X.
$$
Question 1 (not so important). I kind of understand Lurie's approach, but my first though was to try and directly build a functor $B \Sigma_n \to \mathcal{C}$ in the following way: we have a trivial action functor $\alpha: B \Sigma_n \to \Delta^0 \xrightarrow{\{\ast\}} \text{Cat}_{\infty}$, and moreover, an action functor $\beta: B \Sigma_n \to N\mathcal{F}in_\ast \to \text{Cat}_{\infty}$, $\ast \mapsto \left< n \right> \mapsto \mathcal{C}^{\times n}$ given by unstraightening the coCartesian fibration $\mathcal{C}^\otimes \to N\mathcal{F}in_\ast$ and precomposing with the $1$-categorical action $N(\Sigma_n \to \mathcal{F}in_\ast)$ on $\left< n \right>$. Then if one gets a natural transformation $\alpha \Rightarrow \beta$, i.e. an equivariant map $\ast \to \mathcal{C}^{\times n}$, by taking homotopy orbits (i.e. the colimit of such functor over $B \Sigma_n$) we should get a functor $(\ast)_{h \Sigma_n} \simeq B \Sigma_n \to (\mathcal{C}^{\times n})_{h \Sigma_n}$, and then the multiplication map $\mathcal{C}^{\times n} \to \mathcal{C}$ should factor through the homotopy orbits and we can just take the composition
$$
(\ast)_{h \Sigma_n} \simeq B \Sigma_n \to (\mathcal{C}^{\times n})_{h \Sigma_n} \to \mathcal{C}.
$$
This approach seems just a model-independent reformulation of what Lurie does, but I'm not sure how to formally get the natural transformation $\alpha \Rightarrow \beta$ (which is encoded in a morphism $B \Sigma_n \to \text{Fun}(\Delta^1, \text{Cat}_\infty)$); I can get it to work on objects but I'm worried about the higher coherences. Any idea? Or maybe I'm missing something trivial.
Question 2 (the actual thing I care about). For every algebra object $R \in \text{CAlg}(\mathcal{C}^\otimes)$, one gets multiplication maps $m: R^{\otimes n} \to R$. Following the intuition from classical algebra, this map should be $\Sigma_n$ equivariant, so we can take the induced map on homotopy orbits; more precisely, this map should be induced by a natural transformation of functors $B \Sigma_n \to \mathcal{C} \Rightarrow B \Sigma_n \to \Delta^0 \xrightarrow{R} \mathcal{C}$, where the first functor is the action $\ast \mapsto R \otimes \dots \otimes R$. Clearly this natural transformation is defined objectwise as $m: R \otimes \dots \otimes R \to R$, but what about the higher coherences?
Edit: I've realized my question can be completely trivial as there aren't really higher coherences to care about, since $B \Sigma_n$ can be seen as the nerve of a $1$-category and then should be enough to understand where to send objects and morphisms in $B \Sigma_n \to \text{Fun}(\Delta^1, \mathcal{C})$; I'll leave the question here as for now.

Quick comment: you definitely still need higher coherences for a functor $F\colon\mathsf{C}\to\mathscr{E}$ from a $1$-category to an $\infty$-category. The reason is that a strict composition $gf=h$ in $\mathsf{C}$ will be sent to some homotopy $FgFf\simeq Fh$, and you are now left requiring that all these homotopies are compatible in the desired way.

@DaniëlApol of course you are right! That was just me being tired and silly, thanks for the comment.

I can answer Question 2 by using a certain technique that in particular defines the map $B\Sigma_n\to\mathcal{C}, *\mapsto R^{\otimes n}$ in a different (but equivalent) way. To introduce it, I will first address Question 1, and to motivate it, we will first ask ourselves what the difficulty is when we try a more direct approach. I am not claiming that my approach is necessarily the quickest one, but if anything it shows that working model-independently is not always the easiest thing (unless I am missing a more elementary approach, which is definitely a possibility). In other words, if you're a man on a mission like Lurie with 10,000 pages to write, you may opt for a simplicial, model-dependent approach to save time.
I am afraid I was a bit messy with notation when writing out this answer, so I apologize for the less than perfect writing style.
I will write $\Gamma^\mathrm{op}$ for $N(\mathcal{F}in_*)$,  and $\langle m\rangle$ for the pointed set $\{0,\ldots,m\}$. Given a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, we also write the associated map as $\sigma\colon\langle n\rangle\to\langle n\rangle$.
Question 1. The functor $B\Sigma^n\to\Gamma^\mathrm{op}\to\mathrm{Cat}_\infty, *\mapsto \mathcal{C}^{\times n}$ corresponds to the cocartesian fibration $B\Sigma_n\times_{\Gamma^\mathrm{op}}\mathcal{C}^\otimes\to B\Sigma_n$. As such, a natural transformation $\alpha\Rightarrow\beta$ is according to the Grothendieck construction specified by a section $B\Sigma_n\to B\Sigma_n\times_{\Gamma^\mathrm{op}}\mathcal{C}^\otimes$ of the projection map in the other direction. To construct this, we need a commutative square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
B\Sigma_n @>>> \mathcal{C}^\otimes\\
@V{\mathrm{id}}VV @VVV \\
B\Sigma_n @>>> \Gamma^\mathrm{op}
\end{CD}
$$
The top map should be given as $B\Sigma_n\to\mathcal{C}^\otimes, *\mapsto (X,\ldots,X)$. But how can we construct this map? This is essentially as hard as the original problem of constructing a natural transformation $\alpha\Rightarrow\beta$. I tried if I could find an elementary construction, but failed in doing so.
Therefore, it is time to bring out the big guns. When I said you needed to worry about higher coherences, I lied. While you do need to for general functors $F\colon\mathsf{C}\to\mathscr{E}$ for a $1$-category $\mathsf{C}$ and an $\infty$-category $\mathscr{E}$, you don't need to for the specific $1$-category $B\Sigma_n$ in this specific case. This is a consequence of the following lemma.
Lemma. Write $\mathrm{Spc}_*$ for the $\infty$-category of pointed spaces, and $\mathrm{Grpd}_*$ for the $1$-category of pointed groupoids. The functor $B\colon\mathrm{Grp}\to\mathrm{Grpd}_*\hookrightarrow\mathrm{Spc}_*$ extends to a functor $B\colon \mathrm{Grp}(\mathrm{Spc})\to\mathrm{Spc}_*$, where $\mathrm{Grp}(\mathrm{Spc})$ is the $\infty$-category of $\mathbb{E}_1$-groups, and this functor is part of an adjunction
$$
B\colon\mathrm{Grp}(\mathrm{Spc})\rightleftarrows\mathrm{Spc}_*\colon\Omega,
$$
where $\Omega$ sends a pointed space $(K,k)$ to the loop space $\Omega_k K$ at the point $k$.
Since we also have an adjunction $\mathrm{incl}\colon\mathrm{Spc}_*\rightleftarrows\mathrm{Cat}_{\infty,*}\colon(-)^\simeq$ between the inclusion of pointed spaces into pointed $\infty$-categories and the functor that takes the core of such a pointed $\infty$-category, we get a natural equivalence
$$
\mathrm{Cat}_{\infty,*}(BG,(\mathscr{E},e))\simeq\mathrm{Grp}(\mathrm{Spc})(G,\mathscr{E}^\simeq(e,e))
$$
for any $\mathbb{E}_1$-space $G$. In particular, for $G\simeq\Sigma_n$ we have
$$
\mathrm{Cat}_{\infty,*}(B\Sigma_n,(\mathscr{E},e))\simeq\mathrm{Grp}(\mathrm{Spc})(\Sigma_n,\mathscr{E}^\simeq(e,e)).
$$
With this out of the way, we will first construct a map $B\Sigma_n\to\mathcal{C}^{\otimes}$ encoding the action on $(X,\ldots,X)$. By the above, it suffices to construct an $\mathbb{E}_1$-group homomorphism $\Sigma_n\to(\mathcal{C}^\otimes)^\simeq((X,\ldots,X),(X,\ldots,X))$, where $\sigma\in\Sigma_n$ needs to be sent to a map lying over the permutation $\sigma\colon\langle n\rangle \to\langle n\rangle$ in $\Gamma^\mathrm{op}$. Write $\mathcal{C}^\otimes_\sigma((X,\ldots,X),(X,\ldots,X))$ for the space of maps that lie over $\sigma$. We compute
$$
\mathcal{C}^\otimes_\sigma((X,\ldots,X),(X,\ldots,X))\simeq\mathcal{C}^\otimes_{\mathrm{id}_{\langle n\rangle}}((X,\ldots,X),(X,\ldots,X))
$$
by precomposition with the equivalence $\sigma_*^{-1}\colon(X,\ldots,X)\to(X,\ldots, X)$ that is a cocartesian lift of $\sigma^{-1}$. The fact that this is an equivalence means that
$$
(\mathcal{C}^\otimes)^\simeq_\sigma((X,\ldots,X),(X,\ldots,X))\simeq(\mathcal{C}^\otimes)^\simeq_{\mathrm{id}_{\langle n\rangle}}((X,\ldots,X),(X,\ldots,X))
$$
in the same way as well, so that
$$
\bigsqcup_{\sigma\in\Sigma_n}(\mathcal{C}^\otimes)^\simeq_\sigma((X,\ldots,X),(X,\ldots,X))\simeq\Sigma_n\times(\mathcal{C}^\otimes)^\simeq_{\mathrm{id}_{\langle n\rangle}}((X,\ldots,X),(X,\ldots,X)), (\sigma, f)\mapsto (\sigma, f\circ\sigma^{-1}_*).
$$
We can hence define a map $\Sigma_n\to(\mathcal{C}^\otimes)^\simeq((X,\ldots,X),(X,\ldots,X))$ with the desired properties using the map
$$
\Sigma_n\to\Sigma_n\times(\mathcal{C}^\otimes)^\simeq_{\mathrm{id}_{\langle n\rangle}}((X,\ldots,X),(X,\ldots,X)), \sigma\mapsto (\sigma,\mathrm{id}).
$$
The unitality law of composition (and the group laws in the ordinary group $\Sigma_n)$ tells us that this is indeed an $\mathbb{E}_1$-group homomorphism.
Now we can return to the construction of our map $B\Sigma_n\to\mathcal{C}$ encoding the action on $X^{\otimes n}$. By the above, we only need to specify an $\mathbb{E}_1$-group homomorphism $\Sigma_n\to\mathcal{C}^\simeq(X^{\otimes n},X^{\otimes n})$. We have a pullback diagram of spaces
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{C}(X^{\otimes n},X^{\otimes n}) @>>> \mathcal{C}^\otimes((X,\ldots,X),X^{\otimes n})\\
@VVV @VVV\\
* @>{\nu\colon\langle n\rangle\to\langle 1\rangle}>>\Gamma^\mathrm{op}(\langle n\rangle,\langle 1\rangle)
\end{CD}
$$
because of the defining property of cocartesian morphisms, where $\nu$ is the map sending $i\mapsto 1$ for all $i\geq 1$. Note that, for any permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, it holds that $\nu\sigma=\nu$.
This means that the action of $\Sigma_n$ on $(X,\ldots,X)$ defined above can be applied on the first term of the space $\mathcal{C}^\otimes_{\nu}((X,\ldots,X),X^{\otimes n})$ to get via composition an action
$$
\Sigma_n\times\mathcal{C}^\otimes_{\nu}((X,\ldots,X),X^{\otimes n})\to\left(\bigsqcup_{\sigma\in\Sigma_n}(\mathcal{C}^\otimes)^\simeq_{\sigma}((X,\ldots,X),(X,\ldots,X))\right)\times\mathcal{C}^\otimes_{\nu}((X,\ldots,X),X^{\otimes n})\\
\to\mathcal{C}^\otimes_{\nu}((X,\ldots,X),X^{\otimes n}).
$$
The cocartesian lift $\nu_*\colon(X,\ldots,X)\to X^{\otimes n}$ satisfies $\sigma_*\nu_*\simeq\nu_*$ and hence we obtain a single action $\Sigma_n\to\mathcal{C}^\otimes_{\nu}((X,\ldots,X),X^{\otimes n}), \mathrm{id}_{\langle n\rangle}\mapsto \nu_*$. The equivalence $\mathcal{C}(X^{\otimes n}, X^{\otimes n})\simeq\mathcal{C}^\otimes_{\nu}((X,\ldots,X),X^{\otimes n})$ from above associates to this an action $\Sigma_n\to\mathcal{C}(X^{\otimes n}, X^{\otimes n}), \mathrm{id}_{\langle n\rangle}\mapsto\mathrm{id}_{X^{\otimes n}}$, which is the one we were after.
Question 2. To define a natural transformation between our first functor $\alpha\colon B\Sigma_n\to\mathcal{C}, *\mapsto R^{\otimes n}$ and our second functor $\beta\colon B\Sigma_n\to *\to\mathcal{C}, *\mapsto R$, we need to construct a functor $H\colon B\Sigma_n\to\mathrm{Fun}(\Delta^1,\mathcal{C})$, and after declaring that $*\in B\Sigma_n$ be sent to the multiplication map $\mu\colon R^{\otimes n}\to R$, we need to specify an $\mathbb{E}_1$-group homomorphism $\Sigma_n\to\mathrm{Nat}^\simeq(\mu,\mu)$, where $\mathrm{Nat}^\simeq(\mu,\mu)$ is the space of natural equivalences $\mu\Rightarrow\mu$ (considered as a functor $\mu\colon\Delta^1\to\mathcal{C}$).
We have our map
$$
\Sigma_n\to\mathcal{C}^{\simeq}(R^{\otimes n},R^{\otimes n}), \sigma\mapsto\sigma_{\otimes,*}
$$
from above, which satisfies by construction that it is the unique map $R^{\otimes n}\to R^{\otimes n}$ satisfying $\nu_*\sigma_*\simeq\sigma_{\otimes,*}\nu_*$, where $\sigma_*\colon (R,\ldots,R)\to(R,\ldots R)$ was the map defined earlier, and $\nu_*\colon(R,\ldots,R)\to R^{\otimes n}$ is the cocartesian lift of $\nu$ also used earlier. We can hence consider another $\mathbb{E}_1$-group action
$$
\Sigma_n\times\mathcal{C}(R^{\otimes n},R)\to\mathcal{C}^\simeq(R^{\otimes n},R^{\otimes n})\times\mathcal{C}(R^{\otimes n},R)\xrightarrow{\mathrm{composition}}\mathcal{C}(R^{\otimes n},R), (\sigma,f)\mapsto f\circ\sigma_{\otimes,*}
$$
We note that $\mu\sigma_{\otimes,*}\simeq\mu$ (in other words, the square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
R^{\otimes n} @>{\sigma_{\otimes,*}}>> R^{\otimes n}\\
@V{\mu}VV @VV{\mu}V\\
R @>{\mathrm{id}_R}>> R
\end{CD}
$$
commutes: this means that the map $H\colon B\Sigma_n\to\mathrm{Fun}(\Delta^1,\mathcal{C})$ that we are constructing indeed is a natural transformation between $\alpha$ and $\beta$.) Indeed, $\mu$ is the unique map such that $R(\nu)\simeq\mu\nu_*$, and we have $R(\sigma)\simeq\sigma_*$ by lax monoidality of $R$. This means that $R(\nu)\simeq R(\nu\sigma)\simeq R(\nu)\sigma_*\simeq\mu\nu_*\sigma_*\simeq\mu\sigma_{\otimes,*}\nu_*$, which forces $\mu\sigma_{\otimes,*}\simeq\mu$. Hence our above $\mathbb{E}_1$-group action restricts to an $\mathbb{E}_1$-group homomorphism
$\Sigma_n\to\mathrm{Nat}^\simeq(\mu,\mu),\mathrm{id}_{\langle n\rangle}\mapsto\mathrm{id}_\mu$. With this, we are done.
